# simple functions converging uniformly to a bounded function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I asked this question before here and did not get a complete answer. Hope this time it will help. 
Suppose $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $\mu(E)<\infty$. Show that for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a set $F\subset E$ and a sequence of simple functions $\varphi_{n}$ on E such that $f$ is bounded on $F$ and $\varphi_{n}\to f$ uniformly on $F$.

My question is how to construct such $F$ such that $f$ is bounded.

Here is my solution:
Choose $F_{k}(x)=\{x\in E:|f(x)|\leq k\}=f^{-1}([-k,k])$. Clearly, $f$ is bounded on the set $F_k$ that depends on arbitrary value $k$. $E=\bigcup_{k}F_k$, so $\bigcap_{k}E\setminus F_k=E\setminus\bigcup_{k}F_k=\emptyset$. Thus  $\mu(E\setminus F_k)<\epsilon$ for $\epsilon$ small.
To prove uniform convergence, define the simple function $\varphi_n(x)$ as\
$\varphi_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{2^n-1}\frac{i}{2^n}\chi_\{\frac{ki}{2^n}<f\leq\frac{k(i+1)}{2^n}\}$
Obviously, $|\varphi_n(x)-f|<2^{-n}$, which shows $\varphi_n(x)\to f$ uniformly on $F_k$.

Is my method of constructing $F$ and proving $f$ is bounded in $F$ valid? For proving uniform continuity, is there an easier way to do that, such as by Egoroff theorem?

Comment: By "uniform continuity" do you mean uniform convergence? Also, what  is the role of $\varepsilon$ in your first paragraph?

Comment: Yes; Just one of the conditions of Egoroff theorem, which means $F_k$ is a good cover of $E$.